# About non-zero Zero Divisor of Skew Polynomial Ring Matrix $2\times 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

I have a problem about skew polynomial ring.
If I have $R=M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\sigma$  is an endomorphism in $R$ with $\sigma \left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c& d \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} a& -b \\ -c&d \end{bmatrix}$. Also let $\delta = 0$, then we have $R[x;\sigma]$ is skew polynomial ring. Consider that, in this case we have $xa = \sigma(a)x$.

Problem : I have an intuition about the non-zero zero divisor of $R[x;\sigma]$, i.e
$P = \{\sum_{i=0}^{n} A_ix^i : det(A_i)=0, A_i = \begin{bmatrix} a_i & b_i \\ c_i&d_i \end{bmatrix}, a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i \in \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\} \}$.

Let $Z_0(R[x;\sigma])$ is non-zero divisor of $R[x;\sigma]$. I have already proved $P \subseteq Z_0(R[x;\sigma])$. But I am confused with the $Z_0(R[x;\sigma]) \subseteq P$.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the purpose of defining $\delta$?

Comment: Just to make it simpler. In general case of skew polynomial ring, we have $R[x;\sigma;\delta]$, with $\delta$ is a $\sigma$-derivation. So in this case, we have $xa = \sigma(a)x + \delta(a)$.

Comment: Also, you may want to use a different notation for the non-zero divisor as $Z(R)$ usually means the *center* of $A$ (*zentrum* in German). Do you conjecture $P$ to be the zero divisors or do you *know* they are but want to see why? In any case it'd be helpful to see how the proof of $(\subset)$ goes.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for bad notation. Actually I conjecture that.

Comment: I see. I will think about it. In any case, I think you should drop (or modify) the assumption that $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i \neq 0$. The zero divisors of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ should be contained in the zero divisors of the skew polynomial ring. The zero divisors of a matrix ring over a field are the non-invertible matrices: if $AB = 0$ with $A,B \neq 0$ then $A$ can't be invertible or we'd have $B = 0$. Reciprocally, if $x \in \ker A$ then $AB = 0$ for $B = ( \ x | \ x \cdots | \ x \ )$.

Comment: (cont.) hence for any matrix $A$ with zero determinant, we have $A = Ax^0 \in Z_0$, but as stated $A \not \in P$. A concrete example would be

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\  0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: I thought with the assumption, everything will be alright since I use non-zero zero divisor.  And also, what did you just prove ? I don't get it. sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118313/discussion-between-guidoar-and-nightshadow).